# Got an NPE in SBT, where do I report?

Tags: sbt

I have SBT ver 1.3.13, and java openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
Running my project (`sbt run` in [https://github.com/geek94/Akka-Https](http://%20https://github.com/geek94/Akka-Https)) I get an NPE, namely:

```
Vlad4087688721:Akka-Https vpatryshev$ sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/vpatryshev/projects/Akka-Https/project
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1769)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:416)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:253)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1249)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.split(Pattern.java:1322)
    at sbt.IO$.pathSplit(IO.scala:744)
    at sbt.IO$.parseClasspath(IO.scala:859)
    at sbt.compiler.CompilerArguments.extClasspath(CompilerArguments.scala:62)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.withBootclasspath(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:189)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.searchClasspathAndLookup(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:167)
    at sbt.compiler.MixedAnalyzingCompiler$.apply(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:177)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
    at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:128)
    at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:114)
    at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:814)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:805)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:803)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So, it's a bug (even if it's a Java bug, there must be a check for that kind of error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [build.sbt](https://github.com/geek94/Akka-Https/blob/master/build.sbt#L7), you are using scala 2.11.6.

According to [Scala JDK COMPATIBILITY](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html) documentation, the minimum Scala version you should use with Java 11, is Scala 2.11.12 .

Please try to upgrade yor scala version.

Comment: I made sure I have sbt 1.3.13 referred in `project/build.properties`; it worked. Thanks!